# Is there a "code coverage" tool for HTML?

Tags: html, selenium, integration-testing, code-coverage

I have a series of integration tests running through the selenium driver with code coverage tools already set up on my backend server. What I'm looking for now is to check that the browser displays every HTML element (in particular those that are hidden or added through javascript after the page loads), tests press all buttons and follow hyperlinks, etc. It'd be something like JSCover but for client-side HTML.

Like any programming language, the "code coverage" would serve as a reminder to remove unused DOM elements or force developers to write tests and code that use them. For example, if I create a page with a hidden modal, but, in a rush, I forget to include a way to reveal it, or I forget to add a test to press the button to make it appear and use it, I'd like to be able to
generate a report similar to code coverage that says:

The following elements remained hidden at `/path`:

```
<div id=modal hidden>
...
</div>
```

And

Clients never pressed the following buttons at `/path`:

```
<button>Show modal</button>
```

This sort of measurement seems like something that should live in the web browser's driver since that would be the only way to know every element displayed when JS changes the DOM. Still, if anyone has ideas about simple code that polls the web page and checks things client-side, I'd be open to any suggestions.

Comment: Selenium is perfect for this.  For JS changes be sure to use webdriverwaits with expected conditions: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/

Comment: What is your back-end written in?

Comment: @AlexeyR. The backend isn't relevant for what I'm looking for

Comment: @pcalkins Waits look more like something I would need when I'm intentionally trying to test something that I know javascript will soon add to the DOM. What I'm looking for is more of a sanity check for things I've forgotten to test. I think what I'll have to do is wrap some of my selenium calls, so page loads check for hidden elements, buttons, etc. After interactions with the page, it'd recheck the DOM to see if the elements eventually got displayed, and buttons got pressed.

Comment: You might want to look at my hobby project to see if Selenium suits your needs:  https://www.browsermator.com  It'll allow you to get up and running quickly and try some things out.